# Can't find my node js and express project url

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, centos7

I have a node and express project and put it on cpanel. Now I can't access its url.

The path of my project I put in cPanel: `public_html > backend`.

And the path I want to access from my browser:

```
https://mydoamin/backend/apiV1/getGender
```

And I also tried this path:

```
https://mydomain/apiV1/getGender
```

Unfortunately, I do not have access to any of them.

**NOTE:** The server I use is VPS with CentOS7 operating system.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: What is the response you are getting when calling your API? Is it HTTP 404 (not found) or maybe CORS issue? please provide some information regarding the response you are getting

Comment: Returns the website located in the public_html directory.